# iOS list of all US Postal Codes

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

I have a search bar in my iOS app in which I have a list of postal codes come up when a user begins typing.  I would like that array list that populates to include all US postal codes, and it's an NSArray I would like I could create using CLPlacemark of the CoreLocation Framework.

Here is the declaration from the documentation:
     @property(nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString *postalCode

I'm looking for insight on how I can extract the NSArray in CoreLocation which holds this list of postal codes?  If not, is there any easier way without typing out all zip codes or using a 3rd party library?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're trying to get a list of all US postal (Zip) codes from Core Location, but it's not at all clear that the list you envision even exists in the framework. Have you ever seen the [USPS Zip Code Directory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1601758820)? It's thousands of pages long, and it changes every year. Instead, you should probably be looking for a service that'll provide the relevant Zip codes for a given geographic area.

Comment: Based on how you can use Reverse Geocode Current Location to get zip code from GPS, those zip codes have to be stores in CoreLocation somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you've made a false assumption — `CLGeocoder` etc require network access to perform the CLPlacemerk lookup.
From [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/corelocation/reference/clgeocoder_class/index.html):

> A geocoder object is a single-shot object that works with a network-based service to look up placemark information for its specified coordinate value.

Which makes sense if you think about it, zip/postal codes change frequently and are not just limited to the US… and th[e list of supported and partially supported countries](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2289/_index.html) is growing with IOS updates